# Cakephp httpsocket ssl doesn't work with console shells

Tags: shell, cakephp, ssl, console

I'm trying to make a cakephp shell use httpsocket, with ssl.

My "strawman" shell:

```
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class UpdaterShell extends AppShell {

public function main() {      
    // STRAWMAN
    $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $results = $httpSocket->post(
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        'foo=bar'
    );
    debug($results);
}   
}
```

Now, I don't expect a successful response from Google, since in this simple test I haven't provided the necessary params.

But what I do get is: **`Error@ unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured php?`**

I didn't, openssl is enabled, and to prove it, this works:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Network/Http');

class StrawmanController extends AppController {

public function index() {
    // STRAWMAN
    $httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
    $results = $httpSocket->post(
        'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
        'foo=bar'
    );
    debug($results);   
}  
}
```

(and by works, I mean responds with "invalid_request".)

To summarize: openssl works when I use it through a controller or model, but not through the console.

Does anyone know why, and how I can make it work?

Thanks! A

Comment: PS: both work fine with normal-assed http://

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console PHP and web PHP usually are not the same.
Both have different PHP.ini files, thus resulting in some modules not enabled in CLI which you take for granted via web interface.

Make sure you find the right PHP.ini for CLI and enable the SSL module openssl there, as well.

Comment: Correct! Once I knew what to look for, `php --ini` showed me that on this laptop there was a third php.ini file I'd forgotten about, and that didn't have opensll on. Note to the wary: install both xampp and wamp on the same machine at your own risk, and only ever when you're getting paid to do so!

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark)'s answer.

```
$httpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$request = array(
         'method' => 'POST',
         'uri' => array(
                    'schema' => 'https',
                    'host' => 'www.samplewebsite.com',
                    'path' => 'put/your/path/here'
                    )
     );
$result = $httpSocket->request($request);
```

check out for openssl `*nix` distros

```
 php -r "phpinfo();" | grep ssl
```

For windows, I guess it's called `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`